# if else command in IBM AIX OS

Tags: awk, grep, passwords, aix

I would check in the `/etc/security/passwd` file if a `password` is assigned to `root` user.
We have to types of results:

```
root:
        password = *
or
root:
        password = {ssha512}***********
```

i wrote a command to return `ok` if the password assigned is a `hashed` one and the exact output
if no password is assigned

```
root:
        password = *
```

this is my command `grep -p 'password = ' /etc/security/passwd | grep -p '^root:' | awk -F= '{gsub(/ /, "", $2); print $2}' | awk -F: '{if ($1 != "" && $2 != "*") print "ok"; else print $2}'` 
the problem is that the command return only `OK` when it's hashed password but no output yeld in the other case.
how could i modify the command to get the requested one.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what the `-p` flag is suppose to do.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following GNU `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS='root:\\n[[:space:]]*password = \\*+\\n' 'RT{print "OK"}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

`@medisamm` : what about now :

```
echo 'root:
            password = *
   or
      root:
            password = {ssha512}***********' |
```

---

```
 mawk '/password = / * NF^_ ? ($!NF = $NF)^--_ : (_+= /^root: /)-_'
```

---

```
*
{ssha512}***********
```

Comment: it's giving the same output as my command

Comment: @medisamm : updated - see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I was trying and this command was giving what I am looking for:

```
grep -p 'password = ' /test/test1 | grep -p '^root:' | awk -F'= ' '{ if ($2 == "*") print; else if ($2 ~ /{ssha[[:alnum:]]+}/) print "ok" }'

grep -p 'password = ' /test/test2 | grep -p '^root:' | awk -F'= ' '{ if ($2 == "*") print; else if ($2 ~ /{ssha[[:alnum:]]+}/) print "ok" }'
oK

grep -p 'password = ' /test/test1 | grep -p '^root:' | awk -F'= ' '{ if ($2 == "*") print; else if ($2 ~ /{ssha[[:alnum:]]+}/) print "ok" }'
     password = *
```